# Executing command prompt commands from nullsoft scriptable install system(nsis) .

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

I want to make a installer using nsis , but i can't find a example which shows how to execute a command prompt commands on some files using nsis . Is it possible or i am completely off track ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to run an external command, like a third-party installer or a system command from your own NSIS installer?

I think you are looking for [ExecWait](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.4) command.

And the [Embedding other installers](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Embedding_other_installers) section of the NSIS wiki may also be of interest.